# Finding similar data and putting them on separate list

Tags: python

I have bunch of data points (x,y,z) in an array:

```
[58.9067649841309, 57.8828468322754, -50.0]
[63.3353118896484, 62.7399787902832, -50.0]
[73.3353118896484, 62.8352203369141, -50.0]
...
[75.9067916870117, 39.9781227111816, -15.0]
[77.5257720947266, 58.3114356994629, -15.0]
[58.9067649841309, 57.8828468322754, -15.0]
```

and need to find the points that have matching y and put them in a separate lists.  I have done few hours of searching with various methods without luck.

Update: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I can group them using the sort function but can't figure how to put them in a separate list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to sort them by Y axis:

```
sl = sorted(data, key=lambda l:l[1])
```

then you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

groupby(sl, key=lambda l:l[1])
```

---

To print:

```
for i, g in groupby(sl, key=lambda l:l[1]):
    print str(i) + ":"
    for x, y, z in g:
        print x, y, z

39.9781227112:
75.906791687 39.9781227112 -15.0
57.8828468323:
58.9067649841 57.8828468323 -50.0
58.9067649841 57.8828468323 -15.0
58.3114356995:
77.5257720947 58.3114356995 -15.0
62.7399787903:
63.3353118896 62.7399787903 -50.0
62.8352203369:
73.3353118896 62.8352203369 -50.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want [`itertools.groupby(L, key=lambda r: r[2])`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: L needs to be sorted before passing it to `groupby`, and it seems the index is 1..?