# How can I sort this list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list which contains a simple object of a class, say Person i.e:

```
my_list [Person<obj>, Person<obj> ..]
```

This `Person object` is very simple, has various variables, values i.e:

```
Person_n.name = 'Philip'
Person_n.height = '180'
Person_n.lives_in = 'apartment'
```

So as you can see, all these `Person`s live somewhere whether: apartment, house or boat.

What I want to create is a **new list**, or **a dictionary** (does **not** matter which) in which I have this **list sorted** in a way that they are **grouped by their lives_in values** and the **most populated choice is the number one** in the new list (or dictionary, in which lives_in value would be the key).

E.g.:

```
new_list = [('apartment', [Person_1, Person_5, Person_6, Person_4]), ('house': [Person_2, Peson_7]), ('boat': [Person_3])]
```

I am new to Python and I am stuck with endless loops. There must be a simple way to do this without looping through 4 times.

What is the Pythonic way to achieve this desired new list?

Comment: Two steps: `sorted` to sort the list, and then `itertools.groupby` to group them by a key.  Try with those two, and then update the question if you run into an issue. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096955/finding-similar-data-and-putting-them-on-seperate-list) for more information.

Comment: As a side note: it's usually a good idea to write a `__repr__` or a `__str__` for your classes so that you can see something meaningful when you put instances of you class into a list

Comment: @inspectorG4dget To nitpick, you shouldn't change `__repr__` for readability purpose, but only change `__str__`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Comment: To continue: `__repr__` should always return a representation that can be evaluated to get the original object, which may not necessarily be human readable. `__str__` though, is for human readability purpose.

Comment: Burhan, Mr. Inspector, Kay and Kay, I thank all three of you for your help. All this information is very valuable and from a tiny question I learnt a lot more essentials. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to sort it first before passing it to `groupby`:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x.lives_in)
```

then use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x: x.lives_in)
result = [(key, list(group)) \
        for key, group in groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x: x.lives_in)]
```

Comment: Thank you @KayZhu for this answer and the explanation. I just have one more question to make things more complex. Say no matter how many items it contains, I want a certain group to be always last in the new ordered list. What would I do then besides looking for it's key, popping it and appending it to end?

Comment: By the way, I just realised, unless I am doing something wrong, this do not sort the groups by their population?

Comment: @Phil second question first: each group contains all the `Person`s who has the same `lives_in` attribute, and it is sorted by the alphabetical order of `lives_in`

Comment: @Phil first question, yes I think the easiest is just to pop it then append it to the end again

Comment: @Phil if you want to sort the groups by their population (the number of people who live in the same place), you can use `sorted_result = sorted(result, key=lambda x:len(x[1]))`

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I wish there was a better way other than sorting 3 times but I guess that's life. ;-)

Comment: @Phil glad to help :) and just to be clear, it is actually only sorting twice, groupby doesn't really sort it, only to group it by key :)

Answer (score 3):

```
people = my_list_of_people
people.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('lives_in')) # sort the people by where they live
groups = itertools.groupby(people, key=operator.attrgetter('lives_in')) # group the sorted people by where they live
```

Comment: I was trying something else, but thanks for the tip. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your Person list is in `myList` and you want to create `newList`. I'm kind of new to stack overflow so I'm not using tabs. Can someone help me out lol. But here's the code:

```
for i in xrange(len(myList)):
     found = false;
     for j in xrange(len(newList)):
          if newList[j][0]==myList[i].lives_in:
                found = true;
                 newList[j][1].append(myList[i]);
     if !found:
          newList.append((myList[i].lives_in, [myList[i]]))
```